# Any relation between SQL Server Service Name and Instance Name?

Tags: sql-server-2008

My SQL Server's instance name is **SQLEXPRESS** and SQL Server Service Name looks like **MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS**. Is there any relation between instance name and service name? I'm trying to **check SQL Server Service Status by name** and I wonder can SQL Server Service name be different on another computers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the service name is always `MSSQL$<Instance Name>` for a named instance and `MSSQLSERVER` for a default instance. I don't believe either can be altered or overridden, nor can I think of any reason why you'd want to.

You can enumerate the installed instances on a server via the registry, using Powershell for example:

```
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'
```

Comment: +1 for the answer regarding instance names.  That being said, I do prefer not to use the registry directly in powershell unless there isn't another way.  For that part, I prefer the approach taken by @ThomasStringer.  Using WMI is definitely a more reliable approach.

Answer (score 7):

Mark showed you a way to get this information directly from the registry, but another way to do this would be through WMI, consumed by PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "YourDestinationServer" -Namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\computermanagement11" -Class "SqlService" |
    Where-Object {$_.SQLServiceType -eq 1} |
    Select-Object ServiceName, DisplayName, 
        @{Name = "StateDesc"; Expression = {
            switch ($_.State) {
                1 { "Stopped" }
                2 { "Start Pending" }
                3 { "Stop Pending" }
                4 { "Running" }
                5 { "Continue Pending" }
                6 { "Pause Pending" }
                7 { "Paused" }
            }
        }}
```

The above command will give you the state of the SQL Server engine service(s) on a particular machine.

Comment: I can then assume that the following logic is correct then for named and unnamed instances as service name? svcname = instancename != string.Empty ? string.Format("MSSQL${0}", instancename) : "MSSQLSERVER";